# Remove specific inadvertent line breaks with awk?

Tags: awk, sed, newline

I have a 10M line file with spurious line breaks that I want to remove. An example line is:

```
uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four
field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```

I want this to be:

```
uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```

I tried using sed with:

```
sed -z 's/four\n/four /g' input.txt
```

Oddly, the sed command works, but only on small subsets of the file produced with `head -500000 input.txt`. Seems people are suggesting awk instead of sed, but I don't know awk and cannot put together the correct awk command. Any clues?

I'm trying to build up a filter that works. As a test, I tried:

```
awk '/four\n/ {print}' input.text
```

but get no output at all.

Comment: Can your fields be quoted and contain commas, e.g. `field one,"field, two",field three`? If so it's very important to include such fields in your sample input/output. Also, if you don't really have a blank after every comma in your input then don't show that in your example as it can add unnecessary complexity to a solution and can cause people to post solutions that won't work on your real data.

Comment: Are you sure those mid-field line breaks aren't occurring within quoted fields? If so then THAT would be valid CSV but what you show with line breaks inside unquoted fields is not valid CSV per [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Comment: Not all linebreaks are the same. For example, when Excel exports a CSV that has fields that contain linebreaks it uses linefeed (LF) on it's own for the mid-field linebreaks and carriage-return linefeed (CR LF) for the end of row linebreaks. Is that what your input has or something else? You can check with `od -c` or `cat -A` or similar.

Comment: The most clear, simple, efficient, robust, portable solution for you depends on the answers to my comments above. Without those answers we're just guessing at what you really need.

Answer (score 3):

> Oddly, the sed command works, but only on small subsets

In `sed -z 's/four\n/four /g' input.txt` you have used `-z` which [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) explains following way

> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the
> ASCII ‘NUL’ character) instead of a newline.

If your file does not contain `\000` byte anywhere `sed` will treat whole file as single line, which lead to failure if that does not fit into available memory.

```
awk '/four\n/ {print}' input.text
```

GNU AWK by default split lines at newlines and lines do not include newlines, in order to say line ending with `four` you should write `/four$/`. I would use GNU AWK for this task following way, let `input.txt` content be

```
uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four
field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```

then

```
awk '{ORS=/four$/?" ":"\n";print}' input.txt
```

gives output

```
uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```

Explanation: I set output row separator using so-called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse if line ends with `four` it is space else it is newline character. If you want to know more about `ORS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

If you are strictly limited to using GNU `sed` and last line **never** ends with `four` and lines ending with four are **never** adjacent then this can be done following way

```
sed -e '/four$/N' -e 's/\n/ /' input.txt
```

Explanation: when line ends with four do [N command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html) that is

> Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input
> to the pattern space.

then substitute newline character using space.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/,/&/4;t;N;s/\n/ /;ta' file
```

If a line contains 4 or more `,`'s do no further processing and print it.

Otherwise, append the next line, replace the newline by a space and go again.

Answer (score 0):

With `-z` you are limited by the available memory. Moreover, it is not portable to other `sed` than GNU. And `sed -z 's/four\n/four /g'` has a small extra defect: if the last line ends with `four` and a newline character this newline character is replaced with a space (probably unwanted), which leaves the last line without an ending newline character (probably also unwanted).

With any POSIX-compliant `sed`:

```
sed ':a;$!{/four$/{N;ba;};};s/\n/ /g' input.txt
```

This does not slurp the complete input in memory and works as expected even if several consecutive lines end with `four`. It works also if the last line ends with `four` and, in this case, it does not add an extra space at the end of this last line and keeps the final newline character.

Explanations:

- `:a`: declare loop label `a`,
- `$!{...}`: run `...` commands on all lines except the last,
- `/four$/{N;ba;}`: if the line ends with `four`, append the next line to the current one, separated by a newline character, and branch to label `a`,
- `s/\n/ /g`: replace all newline characters with spaces.

Note: theoretically this is also limited by the available memory. If you have thousands of consecutive lines ending with `four` the loop will concatenate them in memory and you could hit the wall.

Answer (score 0):

if a split line does not end in 'field' then maybe this will work:

```
awk '
{ if (prev != "") { curr_line = prev OFS $0 }
  else { curr_line = $0 }
  if ($NF == "field") { print curr_line; prev="" }
  else { prev = curr_line }
}              
' input.txt

uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf("%s%s", $0, ($NF=="field" ? "\n" : " "))}' file
uno field, dos field, tres field, cuatro field, cinco field, seis field, siete field
one field, two field, three field, four field, five field
ichi field, ni field, san field
```